# Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac2n)^{-n^2}\frac1{e^{2n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I determine the convergence or divergence of this series ? The root test doesn't give information here.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{-n^2}\frac1{e^{2n}}$$

Comment: HINT: $\lim_n a_n = 1$, thus the series is divergent.

Comment: @Crostul $\lim_n a_n \not= 1$

Comment: $\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{-n^2}|_{n=2}=\infty\enspace$ , perhaps you meant $\,$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{n^2}\frac1{e^{2n}}$$\,$ ?

Comment: @Crostul : $\, \lim_n a_n = e^2\,$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Consider the limit of the $n$-th term
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to +\infty}(1-2/n)^{-n^2}e^{-2n}=
\lim_{n\to +\infty}\exp(-n^2\ln(1-2/n)-2n)$$
and show that it is **not** zero (but different from $1$). What may we conclude?

P.S. The index $n$ should be greater than $2$ otherwise $a_2$ is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Notice $e^x \ge 1 + x > 0$ for all $x > -1$. For $n \ge 2$, this leads to
$$e^{-\frac2n} \ge 1 - \frac2n > 0
\quad\implies\quad
e^{-2n} \ge \left(1-\frac2n\right)^{n^2}
\quad\implies\quad
a_n = \left(1-\frac2n\right)^{-n^2} e^{-2n} \ge 1
$$
Since $a_n$ doesn't converge to $0$, the series $\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty a_n$ diverges.